# how to refresh view component without refreshing page with using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a view component inside my view

```
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("UserProfileCard")
```

and I want when I click on a button only this component will be refresh without refreshing the page with using jquery ajax or jquery Unobtrusive

Comment: What button are you clicking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create div around component

```
<div id="userProfileCard">
 @await Component.InvokeAsync("UserProfileCard")
</div>
```

create action

```
public class MyController : Controller {
    public IActionResult GetUserProfileCardComponent() {
        return ViewComponent("UserProfileCard", <arguments...>);
    }
}
```

ajax

```
<script>
    $.get("/MyController/GetUserProfileCardComponent", function(data) {
        $("#userProfileCard").html(data);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery the way i know is by repainting the .html() of the div/span the page is rendered in and refreshing it with new content of the component

eq: let us assume userProfileCard is a div then code would be like-:

$("#userProfileCard").html(newData)